# Seasonal decomposition - harmonic analysis in Python

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, frequency-analysis

I did seasonal decomposition on my time series using statsmodels library in Python.
How can I get the periods/frequencies of the different subsignals composing the observed signal ?

Is there a function giving the Fourier decomposition of the seasonal signal ?

Answer (score 4):

The `seasonal` package (PyPI, or [github](https://github.com/welch/seasonal)) includes a `seasonal.periodogram` command that will plot the significant periodicities in your data, with or without first detrending (it uses this to estimate the major period of your data).

`seasonal.periodogram` uses [Welch's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_method) (no relation to me), which handles noisy input signals more robustly than a pure Fourier Transform. It uses the SciPy implementation in scipy.signal.welch